# Recycler View: I want my recycler view item(rows) to be highlighted after specific interval of time

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want my recycler view rows to be highlighted after a specific interval of time, say after 2 seconds. 
Searched all over the internet but no luck so far.

Comment: The question is not very clear. Do you want to highlight some specific rows in your `RecyclerView`. And do you want to toggle the highlight in each two seconds interval?

Comment: @ReazMurshed i want my rows to be highlighted one by one after 2 secs. In first 2 seconds first row is highlighted, then the next and sequence goes on.

Comment: Please see my answer. It'll serve your purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not very clear. I had two questions in mind that I mentioned in the comment of the question.

- Do you want to highlight some specific rows?
- Do you want to toggle the highlight after each two seconds?

So I'm going for a general solution for both.

Let us assume the object you're populating in your each row is like the following.

```
public class ListItem {
    int value; 
    boolean highlight = false;
}
```

The list of `ListItem` object can be inserted in an `ArrayList` to be populated in the `RecyclerView`. Here is your adapter which may look like this.

```
// Declare the yourListItems globally in your Activity
List<ListItem> yourListItems = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
populateYourListItems();

public class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    public class YourViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private final TextView valueTextView;
        private final LinearLayout background;

        public YourViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            valueTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.value_text_view);
            background = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.background);
        }

        public void bindView(int pos) {
            int value = yourListItems.get(pos).value;
            boolean isHighlighted = yourListItems.get(pos).hightlight;

            valueTextView.setText(value);

            // Set the background colour if the highlight value is found true.
            if(isHighlighted) background.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN); 
            else background.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); 
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_activity_log, parent, false);
        return new YourViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        try {
            if (holder instanceof YourViewHolder) {
                YourViewHolder vh = (YourViewHolder) holder;
                vh.bindView(position);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (yourListItems == null || yourListItems.isEmpty())
            return 0;
        else
            return yourListItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Now when you want to highlight some specific items of your `RecyclerView` you need to just set the `highlight` value to `true` and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to bring into the change in effect.

So you might need a timer like the following which will highlight your rows as per your demand in every two seconds.

```
// Declare the timer
private Timer highlightTimer;
private TimerTask highlightTimerTask;

highlightTimer = new Timer();
highlightTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        highLightTheListItems();
    }
};

highlightTimer.schedule(highlightTimerTask, 2000);
```

Now implement your `highLightTheListItems` function as per your need.

```
public void highLightTheListItems() {
    // Modify your list items. 
    // Call notifyDataSetChanged in your adapter
    yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Hope that helps. Thanks.

Comment: I am implementing your solution. Can you please tell me where to write timer code?

Comment: Please do it in you `onCreate` function and please tell me if you have any other issues.

Answer (score 3):

How about, in the recycler adapter OnBindViewHolder method, put a [Handler.postDelayed](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable, long)) in which you set the specific time where you want the item to change.

Inside the runner that you pass in the handler, you put in a **boolean flag** to check if the row will have a different colour/behaviour + a notifyDataSetChanged() in the adapter. (You will have to change your data object to accomodate this new variable)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean highlight as in colour the row's background? If so, you could do this in your listViewAdapter

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View row, ViewGroup parent){
if (row==null){
    row = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(mResource, parent, false);
}

if(foo){
    row.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.translucent_green));
}
else row.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

return row;
}
```

Then in colours.xml

```
<color name="translucent_green">#667cfc00</color>
```

The first 2 numbers(66) is the alpha value, ie opacity. The next 6 are RBG in hexadecimal.