# selected row item stays highlighted in a ListActivity

Tags: java, android, listview, onitemclicklistener, listactivity

I am creating an app which displays the apk files on phone in a list view. I am using ListActivity in this app.When I select a row in listview, it gets highlighted and the app corresponding to the apk file opens.I do not want the app to open, I want the row to stay highlighted after selecting it and no other further action. I tried using
1. `setOnItemLongClickListener`   **(but it won't work here) .**
2. `android:choiceMode="singleChoice"`  **(not working again)**
3.  `getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);`  **(working but opens the app on clicking )**
 ***I do not want the row to be highlighted after some time, I want it to be highlighted on click & stay highlighted and I do not want the app to open, I want the row to stay highlighted after selecting it and no other further action.*** How can I achieve this ?

*AllAppsActivity.java*:

```
public class AllAppsActivity extends ListActivity {
    private PackageManager packageManager = null;
    private List<ApplicationInfo> applist = null;
    private ApplicationAdapter listadaptor = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_apk);

        packageManager = getPackageManager();

        new LoadApplications().execute();

        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        getListView().setSelector(android.R.color.darker_gray);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        ApplicationInfo app = applist.get(position);
        try {
            Intent intent = packageManager
                    .getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.packageName);

            if (null != intent) {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(AllAppsActivity.this, e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(AllAppsActivity.this, e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private List<ApplicationInfo> checkForLaunchIntent(List<ApplicationInfo> list) {
        ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> applist = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();
        for (ApplicationInfo info : list) {
            try {
                if (null != packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageName)) {
                    applist.add(info);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return applist;
    }

    private class LoadApplications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private ProgressDialog progress = null;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            applist = checkForLaunchIntent(packageManager.getInstalledApplications
                    (PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
            listadaptor = new ApplicationAdapter(AllAppsActivity.this,
                    R.layout.snippet_list_row, applist);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            setListAdapter(listadaptor);
            progress.dismiss();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(AllAppsActivity.this, null,
                    "Loading application info...");
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }
}
```

*activity_apk.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_playlist" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:divider="#242424"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: See the answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46474418/3145960

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recycler View: I want my recycler view item(rows) to be highlighted after specific interval of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46473492/recycler-view-i-want-my-recycler-view-itemrows-to-be-highlighted-after-specif)

Comment: I dont want items to be highlighted after some time @ReazMurshed, how is it a duplicate ?

Comment: The process is the same. In case of highlighting after some time is just a matter of scheduling.

Answer (score 0):

If you want do nothing do nothing. Don't override method onListItemClick (delete it) and that's all.

Comment: I want it to be highlighted on click, that's what I want , not nothing

Comment: It will be highlighted

Answer (score 0):

Define a flag in your adapter bean,set highlight by the flag in the adapter, change the flag and adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() when you click item.